# How can I get value of padding-right variable while bootstrap modal adding it to body for adjust window scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm designer and not much aware about jquery and had some tricky requirements in my site. As I have fixed header to top while page scrolling. Once bootstrap modal open it adding padding-right to body to adjust window scroll bar but somehow it's giving some errors to my desire design structure.

I've found the solution to remove this effect but i want exact solution by knowing bootstrap padding-right variable value because it's adding padding-right 17px to chrome browser, 16px to mozila and meanwhile different for each browser.

so can anyone tell me the exact variable which gives different value to each browser while bootstrap modal open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly change in bootstrap js which is included in your project.Put your required code in that particular function and it will work.

Function to be edited : resetScrollbar && resetAdjustments